# Get relative path of the file for tasks in vscode

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, gulp, vscode-tasks

I have a task defined in vscode's tasks.json file as following

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "command": "gulp",
            "taskName": "eslint_task",
            "args": [
                "eslint",
                "--file",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "echoCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The `${file}` is providing me the absolute path (starting from `/Volumes` in macOS) of the file on which I run this command. Is there any way I can get the relative path (Path starting from the workspace folder) of the same file instead?

I already checked the [official documentation for tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), but couldn't find any list of arguments there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the answer. I just need to use `${relativeFile}` instead of `${file}`.

Here's the list of placeholder I have found -

- `${workspaceRoot}`: workspace root folder
- `${file}`: path of saved file
- `${relativeFile}`: relative path of saved file
- `${fileBasename}`: saved file's basename
- `${fileDirname}`: directory name of saved file
- `${fileExtname}`: extension (including .) of saved file
- `${fileBasenameNoExt}`: saved file's basename without extension
- `${cwd}`:current working directory

Source: Taken from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.save-and-run).

Comment: anything for relativedirname ?

Comment: @SayanDey `${relativeFileDirname}`. Full list available [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

Comment: yeah got it before

Comment: Just a reminder: in 2023, they have changed `${fileBasenameNoExt}` to `${fileBasenameNoExtension}`. Don't know the notion behind that change though...