# How to fix "/bin/bash: [command] command not found" after setting up tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json for C++ on Windows 10 VS Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have configured my task.json and c_cpp_properties.json so that I may compile my main.cpp program. In order to proceed, I must press

```
Ctrl + Shift + B
```

As soon as I do a terminal pops up and alters me of an error:

```
Executing task in folder C++: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g main.cpp -o c:\Users\Me\Desktop\C++\.vscode\tasks.exe <

/bin/bash: C:MinGWbing++.exe: command not found
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I don't why this is happening since I've already checked that MinGW is installed in my computer with the correct PATH. To ensure that I do I typed the following in the terminal:

```
          g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I also checked the path according to this [figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Wes5r7nzFpaPCPQGQkxxg8xaUDivjmY/view?usp=sharing)

The only closest problem related to mine is in this [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1329) link. I've also already tried changing the file directory shown in the code below using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365124/get-relative-path-of-the-file-for-tasks-in-vscode) thread but I still encounter this error.

Here are my JSON files which are inside my .vscode file:

tasks.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "main.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17134.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.14.26428/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\8.2.0\\include\\c++"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I should expect to see a ".exe" after compiling but I can't due to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending two days messing around with this I've finally able to correct setup C++ on VS Code and resolved the error.

According to the png image from above, I've included "C:\MinGW\bin" within the user variable "Path" under the dialogue box "User variables for Me". After a simple restart on my computer, I was able to build my project (Shift + Ctrl + B) with no problems.